# Substructures in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\sigma = \{f \}$ be a signature with a unary function symbol and let $\mathcal{B} = (\mathbb{Z}, f^\mathcal{B})$ be a signature with $f^\mathcal{B} = x-1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> $(i)$ Find a substructure $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{B}$ with  $\mathcal{A} \neq \mathcal{B}$.
>
> $(ii)$ Is there a substructure of $\mathcal{B}$ with a finite universe?
>
> $(iii)$ Prove or refute, $\mathcal{B}$ has an infinite number of pair-wise different substructures.

My attempt:

$(i)$ Since $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, we take  $\mathcal{A} = (\mathbb{N}, f^\mathcal{A})$ with $f^\mathcal{A} = x - 1$. Since we don't have any relation symbols, we only have to worry that $f$ "acts the same" in the substructure  $\mathcal{A}$.

$(ii)$ Take the set which only has the element $1$ and define the same $f$.

I haven't been able to solve $iii$.

---

I'm highly unsure of my answers and would really appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point (i)**

$\mathbb N$ can't be taken as the domain for a substructure $\mathcal A$. The issue is that the image of $1$ under $f$, namely $0$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb N$. But following a similar idea, you can take $A = \{0, -1, - 2, \dots\}$ as a domain of a proper substructure $\mathcal A \subsetneq \mathcal B$.

**Point (ii)**

A substructure of $\mathcal B$ can't have a finite universe as the image under $f$ of its minimum element won't be defined.

**Point (iii)**

This is true. For any $n \in \mathbb Z$, $\mathcal A_n$ with domain $A_n = \{n - m \mid m \in \mathbb N\}$ are pair-wised different substructures.